# Continue statement outside foreach loop block

Tags: c#, foreach

With C# can we use continue outside `foreach`? I mean can we skip exception scenarios and move to next record validation ? As per my scenario, I have to refactor code to a separate method instead of using continue in the `foreach` loop.

```
foreach (var name in Students)
{

//forloop should continue even if there is any logic exception and move to next record
CheckIfStudentExist();

}

private void CheckIfStudentExist()
{
try
{
//do some logic to verify if student exist & take to catch if there is some error in logic
}
Catch(Exception)
{
continue;
}

}
```

Comment: Don't `catch` "if there is some error in logic". You should only catch exceptions that you cannot code around - like running out of disk space or a network connection dropping. If you're coding your own logic you should make sure it is robust. Avoid `try`/`catch` as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write `continue` statement outside loop block.

If you want exception to be silent, just leave `catch` block empty.

```
private void CheckIfStudentExist()
{
    try
    {
        //do some logic to verify if student exist & take to catch if there is some error in logic
    }
    catch
    {       
    }
}
```

However, empty `catch` block is a bad practice. At least write some log statement inside so the exception is not lost forever.

It's better to declare our own business exception class so we can catch specific exception type and leave other type (possibly fatal) of exceptions to halt our code execution.

```
private void CheckIfStudentExist()
{
    try
    {
        //do some logic to verify if student exist & take to catch if there is some error in logic
    }
    catch(ValidationException e)
    {       
        // example of the log statement. Change accordingly.
        Log.Error(e, "Validation failed when validating student Id {0}", studentId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there wont be a throw or program breaking in case of exception block only with a log?

Comment: @Kurkula Yes, if you have a catch block, and you don't rethrow the caught exception or throw a new one, execution of your code will continue to the next statement after the catch block.